# Second Monitor not recognized

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, vga, dvi

I just got a new PC with MSI motherboard not sure of the model no. It also has an AMD Radeon HD 7700 Graphics card with windows 7 installed on it. The graphics card comse with two ports. 1 RGB, and 1 DVI port. I have two Samsung Displays which only support VGA and would like to connect both with extended display settings. So far only the monitor plugged in via VGA works the other monitor has its led light at the bottom of the screen flashing and it does not come on. so far i have tried interchanging and its clear that both monitors are working with RGB but not with DVI(By the way got a DVI to RGB plug). Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

My converter looks like this : http://www.waroengkom.com/product/dvi-to-vga-adapter.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Windows key + Shift + Left key (or right key)
if you only have 2 monitors it won't matter thou. If you have 3 or 4, then it will move the active window to the left (or right window)

Alternatively, you can try running the following from the RUN menu (Windows + R)

DisplaySwitch.exe